# Back button holds input for request

Tags: bug, android-app

I believe the title is correct but you're the one doing the work so it could be wrong BUT then, the big I found is that using my phone I open the "Site To Pin" button and my keyboard may come up as well as the drop down. Pressing back to remove kb and then pressing back again to gain back the screen means I closed the drop down and then opened up my screen again but I also seem to have removed the option to bring back the drop down menu.

Nothing huge but maybe worth noting. Thank you.

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: SM-J260T1

  - OS Version: 8.1.0 (J260T1UVS3ASI2)

Comment: [The 2017-11 event](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7926678#7926678) stopped the work for good (I think).